# How to download embedded files in an excel with same name using macro or java?

Tags: java, vba, excel

I have one excel sheet having more than 100 embedded documents, sheet, presentations and images.

Can anyone help me with some pointer (macro code or java code) that can download all the embedded files with the same name and save them in a local drive folder?

[Download attachments with same name without overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349131/download-attachments-with-same-name-without-overwriting)

Found this code but its with outlook, but need similar with excel:

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dt30daysAgo As Date

    dt30daysAgo = DateAdd("d", -30, Now)
    saveFolder = "c:\My\temp"

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If itm.ReceivedTime > dt30daysAgo Then
            If objAtt.FileName <> "list.csv" Then
                objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.FileName
            Else
                objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & itm.Subject & objAtt.FileName
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately that outlook code is so unrelated to excel's model that it might as well be written in an alien language :(

Comment: Are the embedded objects named?

Comment: @QHarr Yes the embedded objects are named.

Comment: this is how : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369981/save-an-embedded-word-document-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-disk-using-vba